# Manually select related table data (SELECT N + 1 problem) LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, performance, linq-to-sql

Database example:

**Image - ImageTag - Tag**

Images can have multiple tags. The relationships are set up fine and stuff but I am running into performance issues.

I have many different queries which select Images according to different criteria. They work fine, however the data for the Tags are not selected with these queries.

This means if I iterate through a list of 10 images and try to access their tags objects (via ImageTag), then a new query is executed on my database for every image.

```
<%foreach (LINQRepositories.Image i in Model)
  { %>

   <li><%=i.title%>
    <ul>
        <%foreach(ImageTag t in i.ImageTags){ %>
            <li><%=t.Tag.name%></li>
        <%} %>
    </ul>
   </li> 

<%} %>
```

This is obviously not ideal. Is there a way to force LINQ to SQL to query for certain data?

Here is an example of one of my queries

```
public static IQueryable<Image> WithTags(this IQueryable<Image> qry, IEnumerable<Tag> tags)
{
    return
        from i in qry
        from iTags in i.ImageTags
        where tags.Contains(iTags.Tag)
        select i;
}
```

---

### Edit

After trying dataload options, this is an example query being generated

> {SELECT [t0].[id], [t0].[title],
>   [t0].[legend], [t0].[dateAdded],
>   [t0].[deleted], [t0].[averageRating],
>   [t0].[numberOfVotes],
>   [t0].[imageOfTheWeek],
>   [t0].[copyright],
>   [t0].[copyrightText],
>   [t0].[areaOfInterest], [t0].[typeId],
>   [t0].[authorId],
>   [t0].[editorialStatusId],
>   [t0].[comments] FROM [dbo].[Image] AS
>   [t0] CROSS JOIN ([dbo].[ImageTag] AS
>   [t1]
>       INNER JOIN [dbo].[Tag] AS [t2] ON [t2].[id] = [t1].[TagId]) WHERE
>   ([t2].[id] = @p0) AND (NOT
>   ([t0].[deleted] = 1)) AND (NOT
>   ([t0].[deleted] = 1)) AND
>   ([t1].[ImageId] = [t0].[id]) }

Comment: Added an update - try explicitly disabling deferred loading.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [DataLoadOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.aspx) class to load related objects with a query.

```
DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();

dlo.LoadWith<Image>(image => image.ImageTags);
dlo.LoadWith<ImageTag>(imageTag => imageTag.Tags);

context.DataLoadOptions = dlo;
```

Just to mention - this is called the *"SELECT N + 1 problem"*.

**UPDATE**

I am usually using LINQ to Entities and have not much experience with LINQ to SQL. It might be required to disable [DeferredLoadingEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.deferredloadingenabled.aspx) explicitly, too.

```
context.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Comment: I would have thought this would be it, it compiles fine, but still the unneeded queries are getting fired

Answer (score 0):

why not try something like:

```
return
        from i in qry
        from iTags in i.ImageTags
        where tags.Contains(iTags.Tag)
        select new { TagName = i.Tag.name };
```

That will return a Collection with only the Tag Names. I hope I'm understanding your question properly here. Hope it helps

Comment: No, not quite sorry. I still need to return a collection of Images, but I need it to have thier Tags already loaded, so the server doesnt have to query again for them